# Does your advice to Clementine change season 2 at all?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one, the-walking-dead-season-two

**Note: There are spoilers for The Walking Dead: Season 1 in this question (and probably in the answers). Read ahead at your own risk.**

At the very end of The Walking Dead: Season 1, episode 5, you give Clementine some advice 2 different times. Your different choices the first time are:

> Find Omid and Christa. 
>  Don't trust anybody. 
>  Find a group.

Your different choices the second time are:

> Keep that hair short. 
>  Always keep moving. 
>  Stay away from cities.

Does anything about the gameplay or story in season 2 change based on which advice you give her at this part? Also, if there are any spoilers, please mark it as either a "season one spoiler" or a "season two spoiler." (because I don't mind reading a season 1 spoiler but I'd hate to see a season 2 spoiler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, but not significantly. There are a few dialogues between Clementine and Characters that you will meet in Season 2 (and sometimes monologues) where Clementine mentions Lee Everett.

Storywise, it does not have an impact (you still have all choices)